# Django Admin is not allowing me to change any user settings after implementing a AbstractUser

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Following a video on Youtube I want to creat a website with different Roles for students and teachers. I also would like to save off the School ID in to the user.

Here is what I want to change but when I hit save it does nothing.

[image]

I've tried creating custom forms to use for the create and change but it doesn't seem to matter. I feel like I missed typed something in the model.py or I'm missing something. Creating users works like a charm so that's why I'm confused why it wouldn't update a user correctly. I have done a fully custom user class before but shouldn't need to for this simple of change.

In the setting is have this line

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "account_app.User"
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('School Name', max_length=240)
    address1 = models.CharField('Address 1', max_length=240)
    address2 = models.CharField('Address 2', max_length=240)
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=240)
    district = models.CharField('District', max_length=240)
    state = models.CharField('State', max_length=2)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField('Zip Code')
    country =models.CharField('Country', max_length=240)
    phone = models.IntegerField('School Phone Number')
    time_zone = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class User(AbstractUser):
    class Role(models.TextChoices):
        ADMIN = "ADMIN", "Admin"
        STUDENT = "STUDENT", "Student"
        TEACHER = "TEACHER", "Teacher"

    base_role = Role.ADMIN

    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Role.choices)
    school_id = models.ForeignKey(School,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.role = self.base_role
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class StudentManager(BaseUserManager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        results = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return results.filter(role=User.Role.STUDENT)


class Student(User):

    base_role = User.Role.STUDENT

    student = StudentManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.role = User.role.STUDENT
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def welcome(self):
        return "Only for students"


class TeacherManager(BaseUserManager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        results = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return results.filter(role=User.Role.TEACHER)


class Teacher(User):

    base_role = User.Role.TEACHER

    teacher = TeacherManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.role = User.role.TEACHER
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def welcome(self):
        return "Only for teachers"
```

this is the admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User
from .models import Student
from .models import Teacher


admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Teacher)
admin.site.register(Student)
```

EDIT - Honestly have no clue how I fixed it but I did change my files

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as AuthUserAdmin

from .forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import School
from .models import UserProfile

"""
*** Used to create users in the Admin
    if you didn't do this it would use the default account in django.
"""
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('email','first_name')

class AccountsUserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):
    # Displays accounts better on the view
    list_display = ('id','username','email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'role','is_staff')

    # Used to search people at top of view
    search_fields = ('username','last_name','email')

    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    
    add_form: UserCreateForm
    ## Viewing an and changing existing user
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username','password')}),
        (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        (('Additional info'), {'fields': ('role', 'school_id')}),
    )
    ## Adding a new User
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username','first_name','last_name','email','role','school_id','password1','password2'),}),)



admin.site.register(UserProfile, AccountsUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(School)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserProfile, School

class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    ROLE_CHOICES =(
    ("ADMIN", "Admin"),
    ("STUDENT", "Student"),
    ("TEACHER", "Teacher"),)
    role = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, required=True)
    school_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=School.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name','email', 'role' , 'school_id' , 'password1', 'password2')

class UserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('School Name', max_length=240)
    address1 = models.CharField('Address 1', max_length=240)
    address2 = models.CharField('Address 2', max_length=240)
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=240)
    district = models.CharField('District', max_length=240)
    state = models.CharField('State', max_length=2)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField('Zip Code')
    country =models.CharField('Country', max_length=240)
    phone = models.IntegerField('School Phone Number')
    time_zone = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    class Role(models.TextChoices):
        ADMIN = "ADMIN", "Admin"
        STUDENT = "STUDENT", "Student"
        TEACHER = "TEACHER", "Teacher"
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Role.choices, blank=True, null=True)
    school_id = models.ForeignKey(School,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class UserProfileManagerTeachers(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(UserProfile, self).get_queryset().filter(role="TEACHER")

class UserProfileManagerStudents(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(UserProfile, self).get_queryset().filter(role="STUDENT")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you changed the default permissions for the Abstracted User Class, So you can try this way to add custom permission for each Model, For ex.:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

@admin.register(User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return True
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Here is the full documentation: [Admin Panel Permissions Doc.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_view_permission)